# VideoCapture doesn't seem to work on Debian - opencv 3.2

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, opencv3.0, webcam-capture

[Videocapture demo](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

```
import numpy as np import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The video capture demo ( opencv 3.2.0 ), on my Debian computer, does not work, and I do not understand how to fix it. I tried it on windows and it worked perfectly.

I tried both with VideoCapture (-1) VideoCapture (0)
But it doesn't seem to work..

How can I fix it? thank you

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn ==
>   3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp,
>   line 9748 Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "ok.py", line 11, in
>   
>       gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error:
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748:
>   error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in
>   function cvtColor

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices 
UVC Camera (046d:0809)(usb-0000:00:14.0-3):     /dev/video1

USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (usb-0000:00:14.0-5):  /dev/video0
```

i tried

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

and webcam works..

Comment: Try directly capturing using `ffplay` from the command line.

Comment: @Vorac webcam works, but with the opencv, example script, give me an error

Comment: What is the value of `ret` and `frame` after the `cap.read()` call?

Comment: ret=False
frame = None

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Using `pip`?

Comment: I recompiled ffmpeg, and opencv, and now when I try to execute
 $ python camera.py,  the output is: ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
Do I have to install opencv-python with pip or not?

Comment: That means you didn't successfully build opencv for python. Try to look at the cmake output. I suggest using `cmake-gui` to tweak parameters and to investigate `opencv` installed modules. Also, you can verify all the ffmpeg libraries are installed (`libavcodec-dev` and the like).

Comment: I solved the problem, reinstalling ffmpeg with -enable-shared and then reinstalling opencv, thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it `VideoCapture(1)`? Do you have two cameras on your system?

You tested

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

on `/dev/video0` so it should be `VideoCapture(0)`.

Comment: Sorry, i've already tested VideoCapture(0) and VideoCapture(1)
yes i have 2 webcam, 0: internal cam,  1:usb-webcam Logitech

Comment: Did you build opencv with ffmpeg? If yes, it's really weird since opencv would call ffmpeg to handle videoIO.